# Animation not functioning as it is set

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I am wanting text to come out of a bag and in a vertical manner and then do a 90 degree turn, so that the text is in a correct position right where I want it.

Right now, my test goes in a huge circle on my page. It lands where I want it to, but it comes out of the page completely wrong. I created a fiddle, but it is really not doing any justice because it doesn't look mine at all. If there was any way to show what mine was doing I would.

I want it to look like names are being taken from a bag. Just like they would be if you had 10 people in a room pulling names out of a bag.

https://jsfiddle.net/n2o672q3/1/

I have these keyframes set to the fegree I want, so again, I'm not sure why mine do a 360.

```
@-moz-keyframes spin {


 0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(110deg);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(110deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(110deg);
        transform:rotate(110deg);
    }
```

Just image a bird flying up and doing a large circle in the air and that is what mine is doing.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the use of `transform-origin` property?

Take a look at **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/n2o672q3/2/)**. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

***CSS:***

```
.shuffle_results {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    font-size: 2em;
    -webkit-animation:spin 3s linear;
    -moz-animation:spin 3s linear;
    animation:spin 3s linear;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
    transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    0% { -moz-transform: translate(0px, 200px) rotate(140deg); }
    100% { -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 200px) rotate(140deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 200px) rotate(140deg); transform: translate(100px, 200px) rotate(140deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg); transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg); }
}
#paperBag {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Just like that except the names coming out one at a time which my current script does right now. Let me give it a try.

Comment: Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Now the names coming out spin like a hour hand of a clock.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of it please?

Comment: For some reason my fiddles aren't taking the same affect as what is in my page. Just like my initial fiddle.

Comment: Try playing with the `rotate()` values and see which `deg` value fits your scenario. If its rotating too much, decrease the value a bit. Similarly, try playing with `translate()` values. The first parameter is `x` position and second is `y` position.